# mvc3 validation function to run once validation is complete

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using MVC3 client side validation.  Is there a way to run a function once, after the validators have fired?

Ideally I want settngs.errorPlacement to run and place my errors accordingly and once that is completed I want another function to run just once.  At the moment I'm calling the function from within settngs.errorPlacement and it's running for every error, which has a hit on performance.

Any help gratefully received.

**Update**

When unobtrusive client side validation fires in MVC, each validator will call either a success or a errorPlacement function. Basically if I've got fifteen validators on a page, one of either of these functions will run for each validator (ie. 7 success, 8 error or 5 success and 10 error).  What I want to do is to call a function to run once after the validators have been looped through and the success and errorPlacement functions have done there bits...

I'm calling the function 15 times at the moment because I can't figure out where I can put the function where it will only run the once.

Comment: At least to me, its not very clear what you want to do. Could you add a code sample or clarify a bit?

Comment: Update added - hopefully this is a clearer explanation!

Answer (score 4):

The jQuery Validation Plugin hooks the form `submit` event with an event handler that calls its `validate()` function to validate the form before submitting, and thus prevents the form submit if validation fails.

If you hook the `submit` event for each of your forms with jQuery, and do it at the bottom of your form(s), it will add your own handler to execute before the plugin handler. That way, you can call the `valid()` function on the form(s) yourself and run whatever custom code you want following the complete form validation. The plugin's `valid()` function calls the `validate()` function on the form, then returns a boolean for success/failure. If you don't care about success/failure, you can just call `validate()` directly instead of calling `valid()`.

When you call `valid()` or `validate()` on the form, it will continue to work with the MVC3 unobtrusive client validation to mark up the form with the validation errors, except now you will be able to do something else after the call.

I put breakpoints in my own `submit()` handler (below) and in the jQuery Validation Plugin `validate()` and `valid()` functions. I only see them getting called once with this implementation, so your validation for the complete form shouldn't execute multiple times.

Of course, the plugin also hooks the focus, blur, keyup, and click events, so validators for individual fields already get called multiple times by design, so the user is provided immediate feedback on failed/resolved form fields. The validation is lazy in that it doesn't run until a user enters a value in a field. Once the user enters a value and leaves the field, the field is validated. If a field is marked invalid, the re-validation is eager, in that an invalid field is repeatedly validated on the various events until it is found to be valid.

Place the following at the bottom of your page, below all `form` tags. As written, with the `$("form")` selector, it will handle the submit event for all `form` elements on the page. Of course, you can use jQuery selectors to pick specific `form` tags for validation. Just call `valid()` or `validate()` on the form whenever you want to perform the validation, and follow it with whatever code you want executed once.

To get the result of validation:

```
<form>
...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        if ($(this).valid() == false) {
            alert("yo!"); // execute anything you want following validation
        }
    });
</script>
```

Or if you don't care to know the result of the validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        $(this).validate();
        alert("yo!"); // execute anything you want following validation
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

They don't have an option for this, but you could do it by overriding the existing function `form` or something similar.

```
var originalForm = $.validator.prototype.form;
$.validator.prototype.form = function() {
    var returnValue = originalForm.call(this);
    if(!returnValue) { 
        //do my custom invalid handling here 
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

I haven't tested this code, I will try to put up a fiddle, but I'm not 100% sure on what the unobtrusive implementation looks like in MVC3 as I haven't used it yet.  If you could put up a fiddle with a mockup of your output HTML / JS we could probably figure it out.

Comment: That's cool. It works in my limited testing with a standard `Html.BeginForm()` form and an `Ajax.BeginForm(...)` AJAX form with unobtrusive JS on. It doesn't interfere with the `submit` handlers, so there's no need to worry about messing with `bind()`/`unbind()`, `live()`/`die()`, `delegate()`/`undelegate()`, or `on()`/`off()` event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest replacing the `defaultShowErrors` function in jquery.validate.js, mirroring it, and adding a call to your placement function.  defaultShowErrors is called after validation is run, whether for a single element or an entire form.

Add the following to a javascript file (inserted *after* jquery.validate.js) or in a script on your page:

```
$.extend($.validator.prototype, {
    defaultShowErrors: function() {
        for ( var i = 0; this.errorList[i]; i++ ) {
            var error = this.errorList[i];
            this.settings.highlight && this.settings.highlight.call( this, error.element,  this.settings.errorClass, this.settings.validClass );
            this.showLabel( error.element, error.message );
        }
        if( this.errorList.length ) {
            this.toShow = this.toShow.add( this.containers );
        }
        if (this.settings.success) {
            for ( var i = 0; this.successList[i]; i++ ) {
                this.showLabel( this.successList[i] );
            }
        }
        if (this.settings.unhighlight) {
            for ( var i = 0, elements = this.validElements(); elements[i]; i++ ) {
                this.settings.unhighlight.call( this, elements[i], this.settings.errorClass,  this.settings.validClass );
            }
        }
        this.toHide = this.toHide.not( this.toShow );
        this.hideErrors();
        this.addWrapper( this.toShow ).show();

        // INSERT CALL TO YOUR CUSTOM PLACEMENT FUNCTION HERE
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

put `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Default)]` above you class definition and then check `if (Session.IsNewSession == true)` so it only runs the first time.
alternatively you can set `Session["somevariable"] = "somevalue"` when you want to excecute your function and check `if (Session["somevariable"] == "somevalue")`. that way you can effiecently toggle if your function should be excecuted.

Comment: Sniffer is looking for a client-side function that runs after client-side validation or on a client-side event in the browser. C# server code does not apply.